# Hide ActionBar icon but keep title

Tags: android-layout, android-actionbar, android

So I am trying to remove the icon from the actionbar but at the same time keep the Title. The problem is that I can only keep both or none at all.

I tried using:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
actionBar.setTitle("My title");
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
```

but this does not hide the logo.

If I want to hide the logo I need to hide both the title and the logo.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `setIcon(null)` to get rid of it

Comment: this worked perfectly along with actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
   getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
```

Comment: this will remove the icon not the space of it

Comment: This also work and no space:  `getActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);` at least at API 16+.